# Testing issue in pdo code in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi this is my php code:

```
<?php

function dbConnect() {
  global $dbh;

  $dbInfo['database_target'] = "localhost";
  $dbInfo['database_name'] = "pdo";
  $dbInfo['username'] = "root";
  $dbInfo['password'] = "";

  $dbConnString = "mysql:host=" . $dbInfo['database_target'] . "; dbname=" . $dbInfo['database_name'];
  $dbh = new PDO($dbConnString, $dbInfo['username'], $dbInfo['password']);
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $error = $dbh->errorInfo();
  if($error[0] != "") {
      print "<p>DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR:</p>";
      print_r($error);
  }
}

function dbQuery($queryString) {
  global $dbh;

  $query = $dbh->query($queryString);
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($query as $query2) {
    $queryReturn[$i] = $query2;
    $i++;
  }
  if($i > 1) {
    return $queryReturn;
  } else {
    return $queryReturn[0];
  }
}

dbConnect(); // Connect to Database

?>
```

when run this code, it shows output like this:

```
DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR:

Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

I want to know, this code correct or not, and If any error in this code, please guide me, I am new to pdo.

Thank you.

Comment: you have to read the doc ... realy ^^ [Here is a link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php), you have to test if `$error[0] != 0` **EDIT** and you have to use try/catch syntax, much better

Answer (score 0):

Don't check errorInfo after making a connection.

PDO throws an exception if connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `global $dbInfo;` instead of `global $dbh;` because `dbInfo` seems to be undefined in this function unlike `dbh`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

http://en.php.net/PDOStatement

PDO::query returns a PDOStatement object. This class has a public property `rowCount`.
You don't need to iterate over all results, count em etc,..

ALL Code in `function dbQuery($queryString) {`

Can be replaced by a single line:

```
return $query->rowCount > 1 ? $query->fetch() : /* else */;
```